# How we can join sqltrace.activity_trace_evmon and sqltrace.activitystmt_trace_evmon tables in db2

Tags: database, db2

I am doing DB2 monitoring : Tracing SQL statements by using an activity event monitor.

Data has been logged in  sqltrace.activity_trace_evmon and sqltrace.activitystmt_trace_evmo  tables however i want the data in single query.

how i can join these tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the following columns: `(PARTITION_NUMBER, APPL_ID, UOW_ID, ACTIVITY_ID)`

Comment: Thanks .There is any link help me to understand these columns meaning.

Comment: [Event monitor logical data groups and monitor elements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html#r0007595__Event_activityLogicalDataGroupdeta-142)
Look at the event_activity* logical data groups.